# Change the wallpaper without delaying using batch file

Tags: batch, cmd.exe, desktop-customization

Using the code down below, either I'll have to open the file a few times or wait for a moment till the wallpaper change

```
@echo off
reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop" /v Wallpaper /t REG_SZ /d "C:\Users\AnB\Desktop\Texts\Projects\Project WallTime\Day and Night\Day.png" /f
RUNDLL32.EXE user32.dll,UpdatePerUserSystemParameters
```

**How to change the wallpaper using Batch or VBS without any delay**

Comment: kill and restart explorer will do it, but you will also close any file explorer window. Also, you can try clicking your desktop and press F5 to refresh it.

Comment: @LPChip , F5 won't work every time and restarting explorer won't help because it'll disturb me and a few other programs i have

Comment: Why is there an issue with the delay otherwise though? I'm curious if the delay causes any problems you are experiencing? How long is the delay that you experiencing without restarting Windows Explorer? Are you running Windows 10 or some other Windows OS? What would be an acceptable maximum time frame for effectiveness for this change?

Comment: restarting Wexplorer works,but it disturbs the user, and it'll take around 5 secs after refreshing